# How can I create a ListView correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm not able to create a Listview in Flutter because of when I create a Listview of widgets the screen stays empty, it's something like that [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZuPB.png)

This is the Code that I wrote and returns a list view:

```
import 'package:dietapp/pages/homepage.dart';
import 'package:dietapp/pages/list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:dietapp/pages/profile.dart';
import 'package:dietapp/pages/createReg.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';

void main() {}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SafeArea(child: TopBar()),
          const Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, bottom: 20),
                child: Text('Seguiment Diari', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
              )),
          Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: TypesListView()),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CreateReg()));
        },
        label: const Text('Crear'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const [
          Text(
            "Dietapp",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TotalLabel extends StatefulWidget {
  final String typeOf;
  final String subtitle;
  final Function() onPressed;
  final double fillBar;

  const TotalLabel(
      {required this.typeOf,
      required this.subtitle,
      required this.onPressed,
      required this.fillBar,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TotalLabel> createState() => _TotalLabelState();
}

class _TotalLabelState extends State<TotalLabel> {
  Color getColor(double fillBar) {
    if (fillBar < 0.5) {
      return Colors.orange;
    } else {
      return Colors.green;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: widget.onPressed,
      child: Container(
        width: 350,
        height: 125,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.5),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                offset: const Offset(10, 20),
                blurRadius: 10,
                spreadRadius: 0,
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.05)),
          ],
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(widget.typeOf,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                )),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Text(
              widget.subtitle,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: 12),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            LinearPercentIndicator(
              width: 300,
              lineHeight: 10,
              barRadius: const Radius.circular(50),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
              progressColor: getColor(widget.fillBar),
              percent: widget.fillBar,
            ),
            const Spacer()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TypesListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const TypesListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      children: <Widget>[
        TotalLabel(
            typeOf: 'Proteines',
            subtitle: 'Range',
            onPressed: () {},
            fillBar: 0.2),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the code, the error view is the following: [image: View Details]

I have also tried to use a Stateless widget returning a list view but didn't worked.

Thanks you so much :)

Comment: Could you show the part of the code where you use the TypesListView Widget?

Comment: I have updated the code in the comment :)

Comment: See my answer below, please also fix your question removing the extra '''

Comment: Look at the structure of my example, in your void main you should have a piece of code saying runApp(HomePage()). Then in your HomePage, I would wrap the Scaffold in a Material widget. I am not even sure how your code manages to render the Homepage since you did not add the runApp instruction in your example. Another thing you could try is to start from my example, and gradually add the other components of your app. The way you used the SafeArea Widget also does not look correct to me, it should wrap the whole app not just a column element.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of how to use a ListView. Note that I created a MaterialApp since ListView is a Material Widget. You can replace ListViewExample with your own Widget containing a ListView.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ListView Example',
      home: ListViewExample(),
    );
  }
}

class ListViewExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Text Widget 1'),
        Text('Text Widget 2'),
        Text('Text Widget 3'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: I have uploaded the entire code in the post, if this helps to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(

              itemCount: 5
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Text("Some text $index")
                ),
                );
         }),
```

More about [listview](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)